# Carregamento assíncrono de vídeos

Tags: html, iframe, assincronismo

Eu tenho uma página com vários vídeos que vem do Youtube, essa página demora um tempo considerável para carregar e em computadores mais antigos, a página fica travada até que tudo seja carregado.

Existe algum jeito de carregar os vídeos de forma assíncrona sem que os vídeos atrapalhem o carregamento da página?

Tem alguma saída para isso com HTML ou só utilizando Javascript?

Os vídeos são carregados através de iframes.

```
<iframe width="400" height="220" src="https://youtube.com/embed/id_do_video" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: [Aqui tem](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/pt/tutorials/how-to-lazy-load-embedded-youtube-videos--cms-26743) alguma coisa que possa ser interessante.

Comment: Perfeito, ajudou bastante, obrigado.